# Why cannot I assign value to a long variable that is between 2^64 and 2^32?

Tags: java, long-integer

I am trying to test the difference between int and long data types and I've learned that int has 32 bits whereas long has 64 bits. According to [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_datatypes.htm), long data type's maximum value is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. I am only using a 13-digit number however I am getting this error:

> error: integer number too large: 2147483645234
>
> long exceedLong = 2147483645234;

I thought a long variable should be able to handle that value. I'm using JDK and JRE version 8 and I'm compiling and running the code in command prompt, using javac and java.

Comment: add a `L` to the long value

Comment: literal number declaration without floating part are by default `int`.
Suffix it with `l` or `L` to declare a long :

   `long exceedLong = 2147483645234L;`

Comment: simply try to use **L** at end of your number
long exceedLong = 2147483645234L;

Comment: simply try to use **L** at end of your number